# giving name for files with processor id and time-step should include in file name

Tags: fortran

I am using **FORTRAN**, I want to give file name such as it should include processor id of the processor created that file and time-step variable when that file is created. 
As the name of file should be in the following form *

> **filename_processorid_timestep**.

*for exa. file_00001_001, where

file -- filename,

00001 -- processr id,

001 -- timestep*

Comment: It looks much more programming related than Unix, but so far you didn't ask a question.

Comment: Stackoverflow with the tag "fortran" is more appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the core number that your process run in it you can use `ps` with option `ps -o psr -p PID`.

For getting the current `PID` for the running process (script) you can use `$$`.

For getting the time in any format you want you can use `date`, for example to get the time with `timestamp` format use `date +"%s"`.

For example:

```
filename="file"
script_PID="$$"
core_id="$(ps -o psr -p $script_PID  | tail -n1)"
timestamp="$(date +%s)"
touch "$filename_$core_id_$timestamp"
```

The result:

```
file_3_1485412526
```

Comment: Is that a new shellish Fortran?  Also note that the question asked for a `processorid`, not `processid` which made it a bit more awkward.

Comment: @JuliePelletier yea i just noticed that he ask for `processorid`, not `processid`, i will edit my answer, thx

Comment: It's still not Fortran though...

Answer (score 0):

1) To get the process ID in Fortran, you can use the getpid function:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GETPID.html

2) Write the calculated file name in a string with a format

Here is an example:

```
program test
  implicit none
  character*(40) :: filename
  integer :: pid, getpid, timestep
  pid = getpid()
  timestep=1

  write(filename,'(''file_'',I5.5,''_'',I3.3)') pid, timestep

  open(unit=10,file=trim(filename),STATUS='UNKNOWN')
  write(10,*) 'hello'
  close(10)

end
```

Comment: suppose I want to perform a write operation in each file created by above code, how should I write open statement.

Comment: I edited the answer to answer your comment